# Yarn not starting after cleaning local tmp

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, cloudera

After deleting all the content of the tmp folder in all of the datanodes, yarn throws the following error:

```java
19/10/16 15:50:17 FATAL nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: NMWebapps failed to start.
       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.webapp.WebServer.serviceStart(WebServer.java:79)
       at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
       at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:120)
       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStart(NodeManager.java:329)
       at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:563)
       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:609)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebAppException: Error starting http server
       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.start(WebApps.java:279)
       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.webapp.WebServer.serviceStart(WebServer.java:65)
       ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to initialize WebAppContext
       at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.start(HttpServer2.java:922)
       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.start(WebApps.java:274)
       ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/Jetty_0_0_0_0_8042_node____19tj0x/webapp/webapps/node/.keep (No such file or directory)
       at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
       at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
       at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
       at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
       at org.mortbay.resource.JarResource.extract(JarResource.java:215)
       at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.resolveWebApp(WebAppContext.java:974)
       at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.getWebInf(WebAppContext.java:832)
       at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.configureClassLoader(WebInfConfiguration.java:62)
       at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:489)
       at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
       at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
       at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
       at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
       at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.start(HttpServer2.java:900)
```

What can I do to restart yarn and recreate these jetty files?

CDH 5.15